# How to use reinterpret cast for inner template class?

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, reinterpret-cast

I have two template classes as outer and inner. I am type casting to inner class from other inner class object. I am getting compilation error. How to resolve this?

```
template<typename O>
struct outer
{
   template<typename I>
      struct inner
      {
      };

   inner<int> *ptr;
   outer();

};

   template<typename O,typename I>
void callme()
{
   reinterpret_cast< outer<O>::inner<I> *>(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
reinterpret_cast<typename outer<O>::template inner<I> *>(nullptr);
//               ^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^
```

The names `outer` and `inner` are dependent names (they depend on template arguments), and therefore you need to explicitly specify their "kind" (value, type, template).

Comment: Great. Why we need to put template in 'template inner<I>'?

Comment: Because `inner` is a dependent name, and so you need to disambiguate its kind.